# Triple Integral Problem (xyz)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate triple integral

$$\iiint_B xyz \, \mathrm{d}V$$

where $B$ is the portion of the unit ball in the first octant (i.e. all coordinates positive).

Our professor told us the answer is $1/48$, and $B$ are the bounds of integration, but I'm not sure how to graph this or evaluate this triple integral.

Comment: are we supposed to convert to spherical or polar? if so, how?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFy-OpajEtA

Comment: @NicNic8 i know how to do a triple integral. i'm not sure how to write the bounds of integration for this.

Comment: I see.  It looks like someone gave you a good answer below.  But let's see if we can see how to think about this problem in a good way?  A simpler problem is to find the area of a 1/4 of a circle.  Can you determine the bounds for that problem?  Alternatively, we might know that the volume of a sphere is 4/3 pi r^3.  And one quadrant would divide the volume by 8, so the answer is 4/24 pi r^3 = 1/6 pi r^3.

Answer (score 3):

Use spherical coordinates for the sphere in the first orthant:

$$\;0\le r\le1,\,0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2,\,0\le\phi\le\frac\pi2\;$$

Observe that here $\;\theta\;$ is the azimuth angle and $\;\phi\;$ is the altitude, or vertical, angle. Then the integral is

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\overbrace{r\cos\theta\sin\phi}^{=x}\cdot \overbrace{r\sin\theta\sin\phi}^{=y}\cdot \overbrace{r\cos\phi}^{=z}\cdot \overbrace{r^2\sin\phi}^{=\text{Jacobian}}\, d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm dr=$$

$$=\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2} r^5\cos\theta\sin\theta\cos\phi\sin^3\phi\, d\phi\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm dr=$$

$$=\left.\frac16r^6\right|_0^1\cdot\left.\frac12\sin^2\theta\right|_0^{\pi/2}\cdot\left.\frac14\sin^4\phi\right|_0^{\pi/2}=\frac16\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac14=\frac1{48}$$